# If is still returning bad array

Tags: php

I'm trying to detect if the user has a google domain.
But it is always returning true.

```
if($emdomain ==  "google.com" || "gmail.com") {
     array_push("google domain");
} else {
     array_push("not google domain");
}
```

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)? You can use it like so: `!in_array($emDomain, ['google.com', 'gmail.com'])`?

Comment: i will try implement it, looks like code i need

Comment: Yeah, thats what i need @h

Comment: @h2ooooooo, thanks ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic grammar error, your

```
if($emdomain ==  "google.com" || "gmail.com")
```

actually equals to:

```
if(($emdomain ==  "google.com") || "gmail.com")
```

And ( Anything || "gmail.com" ) will give `True`, since a string is `True` as boolen.
That's why it gives you first value every time.

The thing you wanted to do is:

```
if($emdomain ==  "google.com" || $emdomain ==  "gmail.com")
```

Answer (score 1):

If `$emdomain == "google.com"` is a true value, then the `if` will be true.

Otherwise, if `gmail.com"` is a true value, then the `if` will be true. The string `"gmail.com"` will **always** be a true value.

Presumably the test you are trying to run is:

```
if ($emdomain == "google.com" || $emdomain == "gmail.com")
```